# Visual Studio 2015 - Heap View - Black Screen of Death

Tags: visual-studio, crash-dumps

I am trying to compare two crash dumps (each of about 1.2GB), however when the Heap View seems to explode and just displays a black screen. Any ideas?
GPU memory (we only have basic GPU's)

[image: VS2015 Black Screen of Death]

Comment: Maybe you hit the memory limit of the x86 devenv.exe process. You could try to open the crash dumps in WinDbg which is available as an x64 application as well.

Comment: How are you trying to open the .dmp files, and, what are you trying to compare?

Comment: Opening dmp's via File->Open File. We are comparing the dmp's to see differences in two versions of the software. Simply using the compare cause the above issue.